# "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'option2' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, variables, return

I'm fairly new to coding and I have this error (as shown above):
the error happens for the opposite variable. e.g when I input 1 I get an error message for option2 and when I input 2 I get an error message for option1

```
def one():
    choice = int(input ()) #the values should be between 1 and 2
    if choice == 1:
        print ("ok")
    else:
        print ("nice")
    return choice


def two(choice):
    if choice == 1:
        option1 = ("hello")
    else:
        option2 = ("thanks")
    return option1, option2

def three(option1, option2, choice):
    if choice ==1:
        print (option1)
    else:
        print (option2)

choice = one()
option1, option2 = two(choice)
three(choice, option1, option2)
```

any help would be appreciated :) thanks

Comment: You are either getting in if or in else. So you end up either declaring option1 or option2.

Comment: in function ```two``` you need to declare both ```option1``` and ```option2``` before returning them, as using if else will define only one of them

Comment: ```def two(choice): option1 = "", option2 = "" ```

Comment: ....adding to above, there is absolutely no need for a third method. You are doing the same in the second itself.

Comment: hi, this isn't the actual code i'm creating. it's just a replica I can use for an example. in the actual code, it has a use for the third function (it's for a school assignment) thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in function definition of two()

Here only option1 or option2 get initialized but you are passing both to the return.
so if choice == 1 then option1 = "hello" and option2 will not be initialized.
So if you want to pass both of then you could do something like this :

```
 def two(choice):
    option1 = option2 = ""
    if choice == 1:             
        option1 = ("hello")    
    else:
        option2 = ("thanks")
    return option1, option2
```

It will declare them as empty strings and then only the correct choice will get changes through if condition

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Accept the answer if you found it useful :)

Comment: sorry, im new. how do i do that :3 nvm got it :)